# IIS8 Entity Framework related timeouts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've seen a few other questions on this, but no answers that relate to my issue...

I have an MVC4 web application using Entity Framework connecting to a couple of databases hosted on an MSSSQL 2005 server.

The app runs fast either out of Visual Studio, or IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 computer.

When I publish the app to the Server 2012 host running IIS 8, it takes up to a minute to start, and anything that queries the database can take up to five minutes to get a reply.

I changed the DataAccess layer to use SqlConnection and SqlCommand to retrieve the data, and it runs fast (<1 second response time) from all three platforms.

Any ideas on how to resolve this, or get started tracking down the issue?

Comment: Is it just the first time it takes 5 minutes or for every single request?

Comment: There is a very long delay on any database interaction.  The time seems to vary, but it is never as fast as using the old SqlConnection/SqlCommand utilities.